# Does $\lim_{x\to\infty} \int_{x}^{x+a} f(t)dt = 0$ for all $a \in [0, b]$ mean $\lim_{x\to\infty} \int_{x}^{x+b} |f(t)| dt= 0$?

Tags: calculus, limits

Consider $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is Lipschitz continuous and

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \int_{x}^{x+a} f(t)dt = 0,$$

for all $a \in [0, b]$.

Then, can we derive the following equation?

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \int_{x}^{x+b} |f(t)|dt = 0$$

Thanks very much!

Comment: Something like $\sin x^2$ should serve as a counterexample.

Comment: Are you sure the $b$ should be in the integration limits in the last equation? If yes, how is it quantified?

Comment: @ManateePink Thanks for your comment. We may imagine that one integrates |f(t)| over $[x, x+b]$ and lets $x$ go to infinity (the integral tends to $0$ as $x$ increases).

Comment: @DavidMitra Can we derive the second equation when $f$ is Lipschitz continuous? Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we assume lipschitz continuity, we can conclude $$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} f(x)=0$$
and hence the second equation holds.

Assume that $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} f(x)=0$ does not hold. Then there exists $C >0$ and a sequence $(x_n)_{n\geq 1}$ such that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} x_n =\infty$, such that $f(x_n)\geq 2C$ (I assumed wlog that those values are positive). But our function is lipschitz continuous with, say, lipschitz constant $L>0$. Then we have for $a=\min\{ b, C/L\}$ and $y\in [x_n; x_n +a]$
$$ f(y)\geq  f(x_n)- \vert f(y)-f(x_n)\vert \geq 2C - L \vert x_n - y\vert \geq C.$$
Thus, we get
$$\int_{x_n}^{x_n+a} f(y) dy \geq Ca >0,$$
which contradicts our assumption.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer! It is a good point to consider the convergence of $f(x)$ first. Then, since Lipschitz continuity means $f(x)$ can be bounded by linear maps, $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) = 0$ can be guaranteed; the proof is very rigorous. Thanks again!

Comment: @Ryan Honestly, I tried to construct a counterexample, but then the assumption forced me always to modify them in such a way that the function would go to zero. Then I tried to show that this always happens and indeed that is what is going on :) very lovely question.